# Socket.io losing messages when the application is closed - React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io

I have a problem, I'm creating an application in react native and uses socket.io for chat functions, however when the user closes the application or when he spends time in the background the socket is closed, that is, if someone sends me  a message in that period it will be lost, I implemented a solution that is based on checking if the socket is closed and temporarily saving the message in a const array to resend it when the user connects, but I have the impression that this is not the  correct way to solve the problem, can someone give me a north?  I'm new to this react technology, thanks in advance

Comment: Check the timeout on your socket connection, I think you can make the connection permanent (either that it never times out, or that it automatically reconnects if it closes).

Comment: I already did this, but it only solves the application issue in the background, if the user closes the process this solution does not work, and when I put a long timeout the react itself generates a warning

Comment: You should save your data in a database ( even if the users are connected ) and then load the data when the user is connected. Now, when a new message is sent, you async- save the data in your db and forward the request in the socket.

Comment: I understand, I had already considered this solution, but I was still undecided because I was thinking about the question of saving one more table in the database, I will really use this medium, thank you!